# How to apply individual column searching on a column that is hidden due to responsive true

Tags: jquery, datatables

Since, `responsive : true` make some of the columns `display : none` and therefore it does not seem to be possible to apply individual column searching on a column that is already hidden due to `responsive : true`, I just wanted to know if there is any work around to make it possible to create a search box that filters the data that is contained by the specific column that is hidden

[image].

I've attached an image of my table, I want to apply individual searching on column namely (Approved By), how is it possible?

If question is not clear or if there is anything wrong in question, comment below before down voting the question, I'll be very willing to clarify, Thank you.

Comment: As long as you got it in the page; display none does not stop you from juggling with it, its just a visual matter. You can update it, you can include the data in it within your queries etc., just as if it was visible. If you already got a filter that gets hidden with the column, you can clone it outside the hidden column and it will perfectly work.

Comment: @Ravenous, You are right, but I'm using `DataTable.js` plugin, so, I was looking for a work around within `DataTable.js` plugin. I've googled it but couldn't find the solution anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this example I did](http://code.buzzword-cloud.com/post/2017/05/23/jquery-datatables-advanced-filtering). I used the assignedTo to column inside the `filter()`. That column you can see is toggled visibility but you can still search on a column that is hidden. While I did this using CSS classes, you can perform the same thing using the responsive plugin. Just make sure you run the column setter code below after you initialize the datatable.

```
var assigned = table.columns('assigned:name');
assigned.search(searchvalue);
table.draw();
```

Also, make sure you define your column and include the name attribute when initializing the datatable so you can properly set the column to a variable.

```
{
     data: assigned,
     name: assigned
}
```

Use [the column search API for another example.](https://datatables.net/reference/api/column().search())